# Website becomes unresponsive during calculations which are there in code. But starts working when calculation is done? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

My code contains the calculations which cannot be broken down into number of small calculations (Permutation generation code)

Its taking some time and hence page shows that the website has gone unresponsive.

But when the calculation is completed, that alert closes and it shows the correct result.

Now, How can I get rid of that alert? (it is in javascript)

Please help!!!

Comment: Your code is blocking the main thread of the website, so user interactions aren't processed until the calculations are done. You can't get rid of the alert, but you can fix the core issue: if it's a synchronous code, the best way would be to put it in a [`WebWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). That way, the calculations are done in the background and the page doesn't become unresponsive in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Web Worker, A web worker is a JavaScript running in the background, without affecting the performance of the page.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp